# How to call a FILE function from main?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *myFile(char *cisfile) {

  FILE *myFile = fopen("cisfile.txt" ,"r");
  if (myFile == NULL) {
      printf("Error");
      exit(0);
  }
  return myFile;
  fclose(myFile);
}

int main() {

  FILE *file;
  char cisfile;
  FILE *myFile = myFile(&cisfile);

}
```

> I'm getting an error that says, "error: called object ‘myFile’ is not a function or function pointer," how do I properly call this function? And is my code not set up properly?

Comment: Don't use the same name for variables and functions in the same scope. You have 3 different entities named `myFile` in this short program.

Comment: What is the `cisfile` argument for?

Comment: Note that `fclose(myFile)` is ineffective in this program.  It will never be executed because it immediately follows an unconditional `return` statement.  I'm not seeing what the point would be anyway, though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because of a very clear mistake in code that's in dissonance with the question's title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
FILE *myOpenFile(const char *filename) {

  FILE *File = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (File == NULL) {
      printf("Error");
      exit(0);
  }
  return File;
}

int main() {
  FILE *myFile = myOpenFile("cisfile.txt");

  // read something from myFile using fread, fgets, fscanf, etc.

  fclose(myFile);
}
```

I renamed some of your identifiers so the program compiles, makes sense and is less confusing.